# How to hide a tab from a TabbedPage when using a condition (xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have the following problem, I have a system that when entering has an xaml with TabbedPage using different content pages such as tabs, but when a certain condition is met I need one of them to hide for the user.

How can I do that?

Cheers

Comment: do you need to dynamically show/hide it, or do you just need to hide it and never show it again?

Comment: when the app makes the login, the  system will makes the hide/show of tab, if the next user is different and have other permissions the question will be make again

Comment: @FelipeParraSoto Hi, if answer be helpful and solved problem, remember to mark it when you have time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the constructor of the page just check when adding the child pages.  I don't know if there is an easy way to do the same thing in XAML

```
public class MyPage : TabbedPage
{
  public MyPage() 
  {

    this.Children.Add(new Page1());
    this.Children.Add(new Page2());

    if (some conditional check based on user) 
    {
      this.Children.Add(new Page3());
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: To add to this you might need to do something like:
`var p = new Page(); p.Title = "Title"; this.Children.Add(p)` if your title isn't showing up. Or reuse an existing page by reference and just set the title again when you re-add it.